# Does Gauss own two “Theorema”?

Tags: differential-geometry

When I read our differential geometry book, I saw two theorema: "Theorema Egregium" and "Theorema Elegantissimum". Mathematically, they are not the same. On wikipedia, there is nothing about Elegantissmum. What is the story behind it?

Comment: Gauss called it *egregium*; see [Disquisitiones generales circa superficies curvas](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX0AAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA24) (1827), page 24.

Comment: What is your source for "elegantissimum" ?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Gauß-Bonnet#Theorema_elegantissimum in german. It is different from egregium, it is relate to gauss-bonnet.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen it... bbut I'm not able to read German and on other Wiki versions : English, French, Italian there is no such title. Are there in German paragraph more info available ?

Comment: Related post : [did-gauss-formulate-or-at-least-know-of-the-full-essence-of-the-Gauss-Bonnet-Theorem ?t](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2520/did-gauss-formulate-or-at-least-know-of-the-full-essence-of-the-gauss-bonnet-t).

Comment: See also this reference (in German) into Gauss' [Werke](https://books.google.it/books?id=XmhzbS1fbhsC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=Gauss+Theorema+Elegantissimum&source=bl&ots=75hw6KK4fB&sig=LPJcJ_54hMMs7PIYzy7-oC4l3Ws&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUk9XlxaPRAhVeeVAKHUjsCqQ4ChDoAQgaMAA#v=onepage&q=Gauss%20Theorema%20Elegantissimum&f=false).

Answer (score 5):

In his [Disquisitiones generales circa superficies curvas](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX0AAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q=egregium&f=false) (1827), §12, page 24, Gauss called *egregium* [sponte perducit ad egregium, i.e. *spontaneously leads to excellent*] the following Theorem:

> Si superficies curva in quamcumque aliam superficiem explicatur, mensura curvaturae in singulis punctis invariata manet. [*If a curved surface is developed upon any other surface whatever, the measure of curvature in each point remains unchanged*.]

And see §20, [page 36](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX0AAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q=elegantissima&f=false) for a result regarding the theory of curved surfaces called *elegantissima* :

> *Excessus summae angolorum trianguli*...

According to: John McCleary, [Geometry from a Differentiable Viewpoint](https://books.google.it/books?id=zfJEIU7YIioC&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=gauss+Theorema+Elegantissimum&source=bl&ots=QgWsC50roM&sig=YqrgRbkeWw-T5kNsxov2yZMj0Ms&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmiuyouaPRAhWjLsAKHXHOBwo4ChDoAQgaMAA#v=onepage&q=gauss%20Theorema%20Elegantissimum&f=false) (2nd ed, 2013), the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem is linked to Gauss' "Theorema Elegantissimum", referring to Gauss' *Disquisitiones*, (1825, §20).

---

See also into [Theoria residuorum biquadraticorum](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX0AAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q=elegantissimum&f=false) (1825), page 30, he calls *elegantissimum* the result:

> > $P \equiv 2a (\text {mod} p)$.